# What makes TPM chip Endorsement Key Non-migratable?

Tags: microcontroller

I know that the endorsement key (EK) of TPM is stored in non-volatile memory (e.g. EEPROM), which is non-migratable to ouside the TPM. The Storage Root Key (SRK) is also non-migratable.

What makes them non-migratable? It is achieved by protective code or the design of the internal IC structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both. The software on the chip does not provide direct access to those values, and the chip is designed to make reading the stored values very difficult.

Comment: Is it possible to create an access through API or other, based on current research? How well the TPM can against the physical attack on the non-volatile memory? Or TPM 2.0 has any improvement against 1.2 on this security topic?